# Table extraction from SQL dB

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table

I have set up wamp server. I have uploaded a table named stud to phpMyAdmin under the database test. Now I want to display it in web browser as a table with lines as delimiters. I wrote the following code as a PHP. When I tried to run localhost/hw.php, the error is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>mysqli Table Viewer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $db_host = 'localhost';

        $database = 'test';
        $table = 'stud';

        if (!mysqli_select_db($database))
            die("Can't select database");

        // sending query
        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
        if (!$result) {
            die("Query to show fields from table failed");
        }

        $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

        echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
        echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

        // printing table headers
        for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
        {
            $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";

        // printing table rows
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";

            // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
            // of $row to $cell variable
            foreach($row as $cell)
                echo "<td>$cell</td>";

            echo "</tr>\n";
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You never perform a connection to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before accessing the table you must connect to the database, this connection is necessary for all the operations over the database. In the next code I use arrows (`// ◄■■■`) to point to the changes (pay attention to the `$cnx` variable) :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>mysqli Table Viewer
</title></head><body>
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';

$database = 'test';
$table = 'stud';

$cnx = mysqli_connect( $db_host, "root", "", $database ) //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
       or die(mysqli_error($cnx));

if (!mysqli_select_db( $cnx, $database ) )               //◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysqli_query( $cnx, "SELECT * FROM {$table}" );  //◄■■■■■■■■■■■
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear Jose, This is exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot. As an extension to this query, how do I make the header row bold and center aligned.

Comment: @MelvinKoshy => `echo "<table border='1'><tr style='font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>";` or, `echo "<td style='font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>{$field->name}</td>";`.